# Firebase search on longitude and latitude

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi was going to use Geofire for this but as its not compatiable with the latest version of Firebase yet I will hold off using it for now.

I have a simple database entry that looks like this...

author: "Aidan Mack"
lat: 58.9551641
long: -1.1091357
title: "hello"
userID: "userid"

I want to send a lat/long and distance radius and get back db entrys like the above within the given radius... any ideas how I would go about it with out using geofire?

Thanks
Aidan

Comment: You're looking for [GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire), which uses GeoHashes to make such queries possible. Not that the Java version of GeoFire is not yet updated for the latest version. It should be coming in a matter of days or weeks though.

Comment: Yep, i noticed that. Ill  wait until its working with the latest version. Thanks Frank.

Comment: Is the Java version of GeoFire now working?